# Xaml- Escape '@' in binding path

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, markup

My binding is like this:

```
<... SelectedItem={Binding ElementName=NAME, Path=MyProperty.@enum} />
```

The *@enum* is inner property and the @ is part of it's name.

The error I get is

> Unexpected token

how can I escape the @?

Comment: did you try without the @?

Comment: No, do you think it'll help? I'll try but I guess it won't work

Comment: I am almost certain it will

Comment: It worked your the best

Comment: Why down vote?!?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@` character is used to escape an identifier name that would otherwise be recognized as C# keyword. Since `enum` is a keyword in C#, you'll have to escape it, but that applies only to C#. The property name is still `enum`.

So the corrent property path is also `MyProperty.enum`:

```
SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=NAME, Path=MyProperty.enum}"
```